# SQL error when trying to join the extract date and month

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to run the query below and get an error

```
select 
    le.a_code,
    le.pr,
    le.pdate
    CASE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM le.pdate) || EXTRACT(MONTH FROM le.pdate) 
        WHEN TO_NUMBER(le.pr) THEN le.pdate
        ELSE TO_DATE('10/31/2018','mm/dd/yyyy')  
    END
from
    load_entry le 
where
    le.pdate between to_date('01/01/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date('10/31/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Error :

> from key word not found where expected.

I have pr (year||month) and pe date . pe date  is not in the same year and month in use the last day of the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma (before the `case`).  I'm a human being, so I always put commas immediately *after* words in SQL, just like I would in any other text that I write.

I would strongly recommend that you learn about the `date` keyword for date constants:

```
select le.a_code, le.pr, le.pdate, 
       (CASE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM le.pdate) || EXTRACT(MONTH FROM le.pdate) 
             WHEN TO_NUMBER(le.pr) THEN le.pdate
             ELSE DATE '2018-10-31' 
        END)
from load_entry le 
where le.pdate between date '2018-01-01' and date '2018-10-31';
```

I also discourage you from using `between` for date/times, particularly for `date` in Oracle -- because it always has a time component.  So I would write the `where` as:

```
where le.pdate >= date '2018-01-01' and
      le.pdate < date '2018-11-01'
```

This works with or without the time component (well, assuming that you want values on 2018-10-31).

Comment: how can I get the date for the  pr ( like if pr is 201809) then I need the date 09/30/2018

Comment: @user565992 . . . That sounds like a different question.  However, you should be able to just use `to_date()` with the right format.

Comment: I have the period 201809 and I need the last date of the month  based on the month and year.